# Calculating a route between two cells, distinguishing between "land" and "water" cells

Tags: excel, vba

[World Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4xsE.png)

I am using Excel and VBA for D&D and have made a world map seperating resources between different cells. I am using this to calculate the distance between the towns and the resources, so that I can calculate the price per pound of the resource.

In order to find the distance between two points (the resource and the town) I use this formula:

```
=SQRT(([@ROW]-$C$2)^2+([@COLUMN]-$D$2)^2)
```

This finds the hypotenuse between the two points, using the columns and rows difference as the other sides of the triangle.

However, I need to go one step further and have a means to tell whether the hypotenuse travels through water tiles or land.

Comment: I do not know D&D, but when moving from A1 to B2, will i go through water which is on A2 ?

Comment: Hi @Luuk have a look at the screenshot posted. This isn't really about D&D and more about using cell references to map routes through a region.

Comment: You should always take your time to give appropriate feedback to your previous question

Comment: Do you mean in selecting the best answer?

Comment: I will ask my question different, Suppose there is 'water' on B2, and The move is done from A1 to B2, should that be possible, or is this travelling through water...

Answer (score 1):

You need a function that gives you a list of cells along your hypotenuse.  Then you test each cell to see if it is land or water.

Step 1: Determine the biggest distance vertically or horizontally

Step 2: Divide the smallest distance by the largest distance.  This ratio is the distance you move in the smallest direction for each unit of the largest.

Step 3: do a for for loop x to y step 1 for the largest distance.  for each iteration of the loop cumulatively add the ratio from 2 to the start position of the smallest.  The get the cell reference from the current largest plus the (integer +1) part of the start plus cumulative movement  distance in the direction of the shortest.

Comment: By the way, the basic algorithm should pretty simple but you may need to make it more complex to include cases where you "go back" (start cell is D6 and end cell is A2)